# Is there any way to detect if it runs on web or not?

Tags: flutter

I'm playing with flutter for web and am wondering if there is a way to detect it runs on web or mobile.
Like you can detect iOS or Android like so.

```
if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS)
```

Does anyone know that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER:**

Flutter Web are in Preview Mode in another branch of the main Flutter.

I think when officially release a stable version you can to use something like `Platform.isWeb`, for while the better option are wait or use Platform.isWindows or any other SO.

Answer (score 3):

There was another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937280/how-can-i-detect-if-my-flutter-app-is-running-in-the-web).

The solution is to use the global constant `if (kIsWeb) {...}`

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html