# How can I detect if my Flutter app is running in the web?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that I can detect the operating system with `Platform.isAndroid`, `Platform.isIOS`, etc. but there isn't something like `Platform.isWeb` so how can I detect this?

Comment: For more info you can check my answer in other question using below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70039641/9985458

Answer (score 299, accepted):

There is a global boolean `kIsWeb` which can tell you whether or not the app was compiled to run on the web.

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```

Comment: if an app is compiled to run on the web and now I'm running an app on android/ios then this code can be executed or not?

Comment: will it give me the power with which I can get an app is running on the web, not in android/ios/software/windows?

Comment: Don't forget to import it... import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

Comment: Is it possible to detect desktop vs mobile?

Comment: it's very ironic that we already have `isFuchsia` and `isLinux` but I still had to come here to check on how to detect for web.

Comment: Does this tell the difference between running on a mobile device as PWA and running on a desktop browser?

Comment: @Deven the answer is: Yes, the snipped provided by Westy92 detects whether is running on Web or not. If not web, then you can check if is Windows, Linux, Android, IOS, etc, by import Platform class (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html).

Comment: Just what I was looking for as I've built an app for both mobile and web site, thanks

Answer (score 31):

If you want to know what your OS is on the web, you can use

```
    String platform = "";
    if (kIsWeb) {
      platform = getOSInsideWeb();
    }

    String getOSInsideWeb() {
      final userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase();
      if( userAgent.contains("iphone"))  return "ios";
      if( userAgent.contains("ipad")) return "ios";
      if( userAgent.contains("android"))  return "Android";
    return "Web";
   }
```

Answer (score 17):

There is a code written Below to get OS/web where flutter is running...

```
if(kIsWeb)
   return Text("It's web");

else if(Platform.isAndroid){
     return Text("it's Android"); }
```

Comment: how can i test the ```kIsweb``` constant during unit testing?

Answer (score 10):

you can use "kIsWeb" to do the job

```
 if(kIsWeb){
// DO SOMETHING
}else{
// DO ANOTHER THING
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Method 1

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if(kIsWeb){
   
}else{

}
```

> Blockquote

Metohd 2

Just use this package [get: ^4.6.6](https://pub.dev/packages/get/example)

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

You can use this to find web

```
bool isWeb = GetPlatform.isWeb;
```

For Others

```
 bool isMobile = GetPlatform.isMobile;
 bool isAndroid = GetPlatform.isAndroid;
 bool isiOS = GetPlatform.isIOS;
 bool isWeb = GetPlatform.isWeb;
 bool isWindows = GetPlatform.isWindows;
 bool isMac = GetPlatform.isMacOS;
 bool isLinux = GetPlatform.isLinux;
 bool isFusia = GetPlatform.isFuchsia;
 bool isDesktop = GetPlatform.isDesktop;
```

Answer (score 1):

In dart:

bool kIsWeb = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.library.js_util');

src: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler (and more reliable) is to use `defaultTargetPlatform`

What you need is can be done like next:

- use `kIsWeb` to check if it is a web
- use `defaultTargetPlatform` to get the  platform

Here is an example:

```dart
final isWebMobile = kIsWeb && (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS);
```