# Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

Tags: flutter

My flutter code isn't running on web.

I found that "bool kisweb" can be used to detect the platform. But my code is failing at "FirebaseAuth.instance". Does this mean I can't use Firebaseauth on web as it might be depending on dart:io?

> ```
> > Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode... Debug service
> > listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54007/NghsYaNRLKE= compiled for web ══╡
> > EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> > ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> > following UnsupportedError was thrown building MultiProvider:
> > Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem The relevant
> > error-causing widget was: MultiProvider
> > org-dartlang-app:///packages/My_App/main.dart:30:10 When the exception
> > was thrown, this was the stack:
> > package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 3996:11  
> > throw_ package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js
> > 57810:17  _operatingSystem
> > package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 57859:27  get
> > operatingSystem
> > package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 57772:27  get
> > _operatingSystem package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 5020:17   get
> > package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 57796:26  get
> > isIOS package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 5020:17
> > get package:firebase_core/src%5Cfirebase_app.dart 15:16               
> > get defaultAppName
> > package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js 5020:17   get
> > package:firebase_core/src%5Cfirebase_app.dart 51:57                get
> > instance package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js
> > 5020:17   get package:firebase_auth/src%5Cfirebase_auth.dart 25:67    
> > get instance package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js
> > 5020:17   get internalCallback
> > ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> > Exited
> ```

Comment: You'll have to migrate to the [firebase web library](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase). [Using Firebase in Flutter Web](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-firebase-in-flutter-web-4b99952180aa).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the FlutterFire group of plugins is in no way supported on Flutter Web. They rely on platform-specific APIs and are currently only implemented for Android and iOS.

**Update May 2021**: As pointed out by Moslem Deris, FlutterFire is now officially supported on the web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web (thanks to Heikkisorsa for commenting the new link)

Comment: Update: Actually now you can use FlutterFire plugins even on web according to official docs: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/

Comment: @michael-pfaff the url you mentioned is no longer active. This seemse to be the newest one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web

Answer (score 77):

I reopen this issue to give a more appropriate answer which is now available in native in flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (kIsWeb) {
    // Some web specific code there
}
else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    // Some android/ios specific code
}
else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.windows || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.fuchsia) {
    // Some desktop specific code there
}
```

Comment: I would be careful and double check using `defaultTargetPlatform`. In my case web app runned in Chrome on macOS `defaultTargetPlatform` returned macOS. [It is not first time that here is something off](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43633).

Comment: @PaulKastel I fixed the example code

Answer (score 17):

You can use a `try-catch` block to prevent the exception from breaking the flow:

```
bool kisweb;
try{
    if(Platform.isAndroid||Platform.isIOS) {
        kisweb=false;
    } else {
        kisweb=true;
    }
} catch(e){
    kisweb=true;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit dangerous, as kisweb is a kind of well-known keyword to detect if the current platform is web, which your code is not doing. Indeed, Platform.isAndroid is true on mobile browsers. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html

Comment: This answer is wrong. as @MappaM mentioned, `Platform.isAndroid` or `Platform.isIOS` is true on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 12):

Due to nature of implementation of library `dart:io` - it poorly works on web (conflicts with `dart:html`). That is why you are getting `Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem` while running your code on web. Web do not have *access* to 'dart:io' in which `Platform.is..` is implemented.

Solution that worked for me, for every system and for every app build with flutter is looking like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

class PlatformUtils {
  static bool get isMobile {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid;
    }
  }

  static bool get isDesktop {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return Platform.isLinux || Platform.isFuchsia || Platform.isWindows || Platform.isMacOS;
    }
  }
}
```

Just firstly check if you are running in web (if so then return false, and write code for web), then check other operating systems.

Answer (score 8):

I have spent last 4 hours researching this issue. All that was already mentioned is correct. However, I'm so happy I found a working solution for web, too: [universal_io](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io) package.

Just remember not to use the 1.0.1 version cause v1.0.1 and other versions don't detect iOS correctly. I was able to go away with it by just downgrading to 0.2.0 version. By the time you read this post it may have been fixed, check out the issue status here: https://github.com/dint-dev/universal_io/issues/8

### IMPLEMENTATION (super simple)

import 'package:universal_io/io.dart';

then just use `Platform.operatingSystem` e.g.

```
print('OS: ${Platform.operatingSystem}');
```

Comment: This solved my operatingSystem value on raspberry pi linux, but my environmental values are not populated

Answer (score 4):

For me, shifting to dev channel worked using
`flutter channel dev`

Web support is now available for most of the firebase plugins.

Answer (score 4):

when you check for web in first if condition then won't get error try below way, worked for me.

```
if (kIsWeb) {
      //running on web
} else if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      //running on android or ios device
}
```

Or you can add try catch block if you want to use.

```
try {
   if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      //running on android or ios device
   }
} catch (e) {
   if (kIsWeb) {
      //running on web
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. In web you have to set metadata and use putData instead of putFile:

```
final metadata = firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': file.path});

if (kIsWeb) {
  uploadTask = ref.putData(await file.readAsBytes(), metadata);
} else {
  uploadTask = ref.putFile(io.File(file.path), metadata);
}
```

You can see the complete example in https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example

Answer (score 1):

When we are debugging a web app, this code will never meet the `Platform`.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

bool get isAndroid => !kIsWeb && Platform.isAndroid;
bool get isIOS => !kIsWeb && Platform.isIOS;
bool get isWindows => !kIsWeb && Platform.isWindows;
bool get isWeb => kIsWeb;
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
 if (kIsWeb &&
            (defaultTargetPlatform.name == 'windows' ||
                defaultTargetPlatform.name == 'linux' ||
                defaultTargetPlatform.name == 'macOs'))
Print('Something);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my code mentioned below.

```
Container(
            height: 150.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropDown(),
          ),
```

Solution: To resolve the issue added below line of code.

1. First, make sure you have imported the dart:io package at the top of your file:

> import 'dart:io';

> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

2. Then add the below line of code:

> ```
> Container(
>   child: kIsWeb ? androidDropDown() : (Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : 
>   androidDropDown()),
> ),
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You must initialize Firebase both in the `web/index.html` file and in the `main.dart` file.

In **web/index.html** file add this code after the body tag

```
<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script>
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "domain.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "your_project_id",
    storageBucket: "your.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1777...",
    appId: "1:1674...appId"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

More information https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/

And also modify **main.dart** file

```
//import the dependencie 
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

//modify the main method
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```