# Flutter Web: Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am not able to run my project on flutter web while running it getting the below error.

I have also performed the [Web Installation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/) steps.

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:5032:11)
    at Function._operatingSystem (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:53023:17)
    at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:53069:27)
    at get _operatingSystem (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:52982:27)
    at Function.desc.get [as _operatingSystem] (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:5521:17)
    at get isLinux (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:52994:26)
    at Function.desc.get [as isLinux] (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:5521:17)
    at flutter_secure_storage.FlutterSecureStorage.new.[_selectOptions] (http://localhost:56113/packages/flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart.lib.js:174:33)
    at flutter_secure_storage.FlutterSecureStorage.new.deleteAll (http://localhost:56113/packages/flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart.lib.js:170:179)
    at deleteAll (http://localhost:56113/packages/ipsgo/src/common_widgets/secure_storage/secure_storage.dart.lib.js:65:52)
    at deleteAll.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:37229:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:37260:7)
    at secure_storage.SecureStorage.new.deleteAll (http://localhost:56113/packages/ipsgo/src/common_widgets/secure_storage/secure_storage.dart.lib.js:64:20)
    at main$ (http://localhost:56113/packages/ipsgo/main.dart.lib.js:422:54)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:37210:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:37081:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:32337:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:32864:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:32902:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:32750:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:32771:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:37333:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:37339:13)
    at http://localhost:56113/dart_sdk.js:33110:9
```

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.2 at /Users/dhavalkansara/Flutter_SDKS/flutter_2.0
    • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (4 weeks ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
    • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
    • Dart version 2.12.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dhavalkansara/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 51.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 54.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 203.7759

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you initialized firebase before using it? like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66992792/9074190

Comment: @NishuthanS yes I have initialized firebase before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The time you've encountered this error, FlutterFire is not yet supported in Flutter web. They rely on platform-specific APIs and are only implemented for Android and iOS.

As of May 2021: FlutterFire is [officially supported on web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58459710/8342742). See [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web).