# Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm getting this error when i run my app. I downloaded the google-services.json into my android/app folder. I have put in the

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

into my app/build.gradle file. Originally i had not put in the "apply plugin" so i put it in later and it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I also put my

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

```
into my android/build.gradle. The entire error when i run the app is



E/flutter ( 4213): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 
[core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. 
Have you added the 
"google-services.json" file to the project? 
E/flutter ( 4213):     
E/flutter ( 4213): View the Android Installation documentation for more information: 
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android
E/flutter ( 4213): 
E/flutter ( 4213): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp 
(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:88:9)
E/flutter ( 4213): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 4213): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41:31)

E/flutter ( 4213): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 4213): #2     
 main (package:rider_app/main.dart:12:3)
E/flutter ( 4213): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4213):
```

(edit: i see there's more to the errors that i might not have seen , i'm hoping you guys will make sense of them)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Note: "path"\flutter_windows_2.0.4-stable\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org
\firebase_core-1.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase
\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: "path"\flutter_windows_2.0.4-stable\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org
\firebase_auth-1.0.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase
\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55393/AAigea5LZbA=/ws

Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...

D/EGL_emulation( 8043): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9c861020: ver 2 0 (tinfo 
0xaa003f90)

E/flutter ( 8043): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled 
Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly 
initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project? 

E/flutter ( 8043):     

E/flutter ( 8043): View the Android Installation documentation for more 
information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android

E/flutter ( 8043): 

E/flutter ( 8043): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp 
(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel
/method_channel_firebase.dart:88:9)

E/flutter ( 8043): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 8043): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41:31)
E/flutter ( 8043): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8043): #2      main (package:riderapp/main.dart:14:3)
E/flutter ( 8043): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8043):
```

pubspec,yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.2
  firebase_database: ^6.1.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.3
```

gradle/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-                                                                                   plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
// this is incase i get error archives can't exceed 64k
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

//apply plugin:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

flutter clean - i tried
flutter get packages - i tried
flutter doctor -v - i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @Nishuthan S for posting the solution for me. As you can see in the comments what he suggested.

try **flutter create** . then **flutter clean** then **flutter run** if that doesn't work you can try back up your lib folder and **pubspec** delete the project create a new project in the same package name and replace lib and **pubspec** –

After i did what he suggested, i went and readded the images, fonts and sounds back to the new project. I typed **flutter pub get** to check pubspec.yaml was working fine. I readded the dependencies from firebase into the correct files, this is found on their website depending on your own project. Now the project is working. Thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your main function add `await Firebase.initializeApp();`

Example:

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Package `firebase_core: ^1.0.3`  https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core

Comment: Thanks for responding, i've added that and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @BlankCoder have you tried ```flutter clean``` ?

Comment: hi Nishuthan, i tried "flutter clearn" and then "flutter pub get" after that. I'm getting same errors. Its strange that the app will load on the emulator as a white screen before i get the error, almost like it's almost loaded but stops working right at the end

Comment: @BlankCoder what are the firebase packages you are using and can you share some code?

Comment: i have added the code, i edited the message and added the code at the bottom. I see it's not very readable so will edit again until it's readable.

Comment: @BlankCoder have you initialized firebase before using it?

Comment: '
void main() async { 

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 

        //we would get error if we don't put wait for firebase to be initialized 

  await Firebase.initializeApp(); 

  runApp(MyApp()); 
}
'

Comment: 'i tried putting the above comment into a code block but it's not working for me' 
i put that into a code block , lets see if it works

Comment: try ```flutter create .```  then ```flutter clean```  then  ```flutter run```  if that doesn't work you can try  back up your lib folder and ```pubspec``` delete the project create a new project in the same package name and replace lib and ```pubspec```

Comment: Thank you @Nishuthan that worked. Please explain why that worked? What was the point behind creating a whole new project? Also i have a new error now but the app runs.
"flutter_windows_2.0.4-stable\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API."
"Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details."

i don't understand this error

Comment: @BlankCoder I don't know exactly how it works 
I think creating the new project gets rid of buggy/corrupted files. 
About your new error Kindly open a new question if you need help.

Comment: i'm looking for a tick , i don't see one

Comment: i can't tick anything because you put a comment not an answer

Comment: @NishuthanS, I too get the same error. tried same trick. created new project and moved lib and pubspec. (flutter pub get, flutter pub upgrade, flutter clean, flutter run) still getting "fireebase has not been correctly initialized"