# How do I use FlutterFire with a emulator demo project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am using the firebase emulator with [demo project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore), without any actual firebase project resource created. I am doing so with the following command...

```
firebase emulators:start --project demo-test --only firestore
```

This successfully starts a Firebase emulator instanceat localhost:8080.

Then I am connecting to the firebase in my flutter app as follows...

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = const Settings(
  host: 'localhost:8080',
  sslEnabled: false,
  persistenceEnabled: false,
);
```

When initializeApp is run, I get the following error...

```
E/flutter ( 7724): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
E/flutter ( 7724):
E/flutter ( 7724): Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.
E/flutter ( 7724):
E/flutter ( 7724): View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization
E/flutter ( 7724):
E/flutter ( 7724): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:113
E/flutter ( 7724): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7724): #1      Firebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40
E/flutter ( 7724): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7724): #2      _MyHomePageState._asyncInit
package:mobile_app/main.dart:53
E/flutter ( 7724): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7724):
```

Comment: How are you initializing the emulator? Here is a good answer that can help you with the [emulator configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509099/how-to-test-cloud-function-using-firebase-emulator/72534304#72534304). I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991781/firebase-has-not-been-correctly-initialized-have-you-added-the-google-services) by BlankCoder that can help you with the error.

Comment: One of the solutions in the case provided suggests moving the `await Firebase.initializeApp()` inside the main function.  The output shows that usually this error is thrown because `Firebase.initializeApp` is being used before being called

Answer (score 2):

My current app has AppConfig class that extends [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) that keeps instance available when in use.

You can try with

```
class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {

    static AppConfig? of(BuildContext context) {
        initializeFirebase();
        return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppConfig>();
      }
    
    static Future<void> initializeFirebase() async {
        try {
          await Firebase.initializeApp();
        } catch (e) {}
      }
}
```

You need to initialise the AppConfig() in main()

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to change `localhost` to your machine ip, in both firebase command line and your app. Some simulators, such as ios simulator, cannot understand localhost.
2. Please paste a *fully* reproducible sample, instead of just part of the lines.
3. Try to `await Firebase.initializeApp();` inside `main` function, not `initState`
4. Firstly check at port 8080 manually and see whether the firebase server really works

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the problem is not with the emulator. There are two problems with the code here.

### Problem 1: Incorrect connection to the emulator

Providing 'localhost:8080' to the `host` argument for Firestore `Settings` *is **not** asking* FlutterFire to use the emulator. The right way to use the emulator for Firestore is

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
```

You could wrap that call in an if statement checked against [`!kReleaseMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html) so that you won't need to comment it out when you want to build the application. Remember to import `flutter/foundation.dart`.

### Problem 2: No `FirebaseOptions` provided

The following error:

> E/flutter ( 7724): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.

is caused from your `Firebase.initializeApp()` statement.

`Firebase.initializeApp()` takes an optional named `options` argument whose value is a type of [`FirebaseOptions`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core_platform_interface/latest/firebase_core_platform_interface/FirebaseOptions-class.html) (with parameters like `apiKey`, `appId`, `projectId`, ...), and you are not providing it.

The `FirebaseOptions` for each platform (android, ios, and web) are available in the Firebase console of a given project. Firebase can't be initialized for any client without its own config or `FirebaseOptions`.

To setup Firebase in a Flutter project, you need to run the `flutterfire configure` command in that flutter project folder. The command will ask you to choose a project from the Firebase console. The command will then fetch configs or `FirebaseOptions` for each platform and make them available through some switch statements for the currentPlatform in a `firebase_options.dart` file.

You then have to import this file in `main.dart` and call `initializeApp` with the option for the given platform as according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#initialize-firebase):

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Note that the command can also create apps for you in the Firebase project, if you haven't yet created them.

##### Let's dive deeper

The `options` parameter is optional, but it is technically required. If you look at the source code for  `Firebase.initializeApp()`, you will see that under the hood, it invokes MethodChannel calls for the underlying platform (android, ios, or web) on which Flutter is running. So, if this MethodChannel is called without `options`, some `coreNotInitialized()` is thrown.

The following is from [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/30216c4a4c06c20f9c4c2b9a235a4aa9a48816a0/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart#L110-L114)

```dart
// If there is no native default app and the user didn't provide options to
// create one, throw.
if (defaultApp == null && _options == null) {
  throw coreNotInitialized();
}
```

This snippet is from `initializeApp` method in [`method_channel_firebase.dart`](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/30216c4a4c06c20f9c4c2b9a235a4aa9a48816a0/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart) file.

There is a conditional block two steps before this one that checks if the current platform is android and if there is a default firebase app available from native android resources. This probably explains why `options` (as well as `name`) are optional at the high-level exposed package.

Thinking deeper, it makes sense that you **must** provide `FirebaseOptions` to `Firebase.initializeApp()`. If you were coding for a specific platform and you were to integrate Firebase or use any of its services, you have to provide those options in one way or the other. In fact, with Flutter, in the past, when the `flutterfire` command was not yet available, setting up Firebase for Flutter had to be done [manually for each platform](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation) (in its own folder).

Now that Dart-only Firebase setup is available in the `main.dart` file directly, it still requires that the `FirebaseOptions` for each platform is provided. And that is what the `flutterfire` CLI does during the setup process. It fetches the configs for each platform and imports them. In fact, [the docs also specify that you should run `flutterfire configure` after adding a specific Firebase product plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#add-plugins).

##### Solution

So it is clear that to work with any client, you must properly connect a Firebase project from the Firebase console, because the client needs the project's config or `FirebaseOptions`.

Since you want to work with demo stuff, use the "explore a demo project" feature in the firebase console. This creates a valid temporary Firebase project.

[image]

Then when you run the `flutterfire configure` command, you select this demo project and use it instead.

Furthermore, the Firebase emulators don't use production resources. So as you start the emulators with `--only firestore`, firestore calls will all be done locally. That said, if you configure FlutterFire with a valid Firebase project, and you use the firestore emulator, you have nothing to fear with regards to interacting with production APIs.

Note that you can use the console demo project with whatever emulator for Firebase service. But remember that these services like firestore for example, are not enabled in the demo project in itself, so if you try to test code against production firestore for the demo project, it won't work.

Also, the demo project in the Firebase console has to be in view while you work with it. There is an "Exit Project" button up top. Once you exist, you've lost the demo project and may have to click on "explore a demo project" again from the home screen to access another demo project

#### Recap

So ensure your main method looks like this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

And even if you are using a demo emulator, it should now work as expected.

Comment: This is and incorrect answer. A firebase emulator demo project does NOT have an actual firebase project created. That is the definition of a demo project (see link in initial post). So there are literally no project configuration that can be done.

Comment: you can't configure any firebase client without a valid firebase app config.

Comment: and yes in the link you just hyperlinked, the keyword is demo firebase project. You can only access demo firebase projects from the Firebase console. That the firebase emulators were configured to ignore any project once they see demo in the project name doesn't mean that the client can work without a valid firebase project. You have to provide flutter with the `FirebaseOptions` or config of at least the demo firebase project.

Comment: And there is nothing like firebase emulator demo project, the demo project has to be from the firebase console. and also remember that you need to connect to the emulators the proper way, see the code 1st problem mentioned in the answer, and not with the firestore `Settings`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781589/how-to-setup-a-firebase-demo-project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245736/discussion-between-obumuneme-nwabude-and-scorb).

Answer (score 0):

inside main() you can write like this for initilize :

```
void main() async { 
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
```

and other thing you have to write :

inside android/app/build.gradle file  at the bottom

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and try this.

[EDIT]

you can check this github post as issue is accepted from flutter as well :
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8898