# How to check if flutter web app has been installed on the device?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-local-notification

I am using flutter web to make a web app, and I want to know whether the user has actually installed the web app or whether the web app is being run on a browser..

I want to know this so I can allow special features to users that have installed the web app in their devices. (e.g allow local_notifications which is not possible for flutter running on a browser)

Comment: What does it mean to install a web app?

Comment: @happy_san by pressing 'Add to Home Screen'

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could build PWA's with flutter. If I understand correctly, there's a constant [`kIsWeb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57965689/11218270). If it's true, it's still in the browser. Else not.

Comment: @happy_san since its a web app i am not sure that method would work

Comment: give it a shot at least

Answer (score 4):

Use JavaScript. Insert this HTML code to your index.html

```html
<script>
function isPwaInstalled() {
    return window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches;
}
</script>
```

Then in your dart file

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

bool isPwaInstalled() => js.context.callMethod("isPwaInstalled");
```

When your PWA app is installed to desktop this method will return true.

Note that the `dart:js` lib is available only on Flutter web, if you import it on other platforms such as iOS or Android, the compiler will complains about it. To avoid this, see [Conditional Import](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#conditionally-importing-and-exporting-library-files) or [this blog](https://medium.com/@dvargahali/dart-2-conditional-imports-update-16147a776aa8)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a Safari Shortcut from a WebApp to HomeScreen is nothing like installing it. It just opens your WebApp in Safari browser

- You won't know the difference with normal viewing of your WebApp

You can check the device with `platform_detect 2.0.0` package thought but that's about it

Link to package https://pub.dev/packages/platform_detect

Answer (score 0):

To extend on [Eric Kwok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71455497/3302026) -

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

bool isPwa() {
  return html.window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches;
}
```

References -

1. [Window: matchMedia() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)
2. [PWA - Detecting display mode](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/detection/#detecting-display-mode)
3. [Web app manifests - display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display)