# Flutter kIsWeb result being reversed/backward

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

i tried to check which platform that the app been used in flutter. followed this `kIsWeb` reference for checking it. this is the code that i used

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobileScreenLayout;
  final Widget webScreenLayout;
  const ResponsiveLayout({
    Key? key,
    required this.mobileScreenLayout,
    required this.webScreenLayout,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      //WEB SCREEN
      return webScreenLayout;
    }
    //MOBILE SCREEN
    return mobileScreenLayout;
  }
}
```

the result was backward. when i run it on web it gave me the `mobileScreenLayout` and when i run it on emulator it gave me the `webScreenLayout`. tried to swap both `webScreenLayout` with the `mobileScreenLayout` and they work how supposedly with what i want. is there any problem with that or it's ok?

this the link i saw the `kIsWeb`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57965689/18627424

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: you have wrong text regarding web and mobile

Answer (score 1):

Please check `mobileScreenLayout` and `webScreenLayout`. I think you added wrong text in these widgets by mistake. kIsWeb will definitely show web when you run it in web. You can also try

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      (kIsWeb)?'Hello World Web!':"hello world mobile",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nope i check them before asking and its true

Comment: Please run this code and you can see that it prints web on web and mobile on mobile.. I checked it before posting the answer

Comment: Look in your web screen layout the text you wrote was this is mobile

Comment: well your code was work, but idk why mine don't been tried to copy other guy answer too and still didn't work.

Comment: well that why i confused why the web screen show this is mobile

Comment: In the `WebScreenLayout` class the center text that you added in build method you added `This is mobile` by mistake.. It has to say `This is web`

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh now i see that, aha thanks for your time

Comment: Glad i was also to help you solve the issue. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.